# Text characters accidentally stacked at the same place

Tags: adobe-indesign

Only 1 file affected.

For the affected text, it is using Avenir Light.

Other text displays fine with this font in this file.

Affected text looks like the 2nd line below:

[image]

Help appreciated.

Comment: What does it show when you select the text box and hit CTRL+Y ?

Comment: Really impossible to answer.. check the Character Panel.. the Paragraph panel.. etc... text wraps..

Comment: @Scott: but the spaces are rendered at the correct positions. Perhaps a minor edit to that line – adding then deleting a single character – will make it cough and spit out whatever causes this localized error.

Comment: Like I posted @usr2564301 .. impossible to know based upon this question alone.

Comment: I found the text had a modified paragraph style. Resetting to the style without modifications resolved the issue. Should I close/delete the Q?

Comment: @Insight, normally when you find the answer yourself, you can simply answer the question yourself and accept your own answer. This can be helpful to others with the same problem. In this case though, people are voting to close the question because it's impossible to guess what is wrong.